# Merge 2 columns into one column after joins

Tags: sql, inner-join

I am not sure if this makes any sense to want to do. 
I come from a programmer background and for me this should make sense to do. 
I have basic SQL experience so i know in basis what i am doing, but data modeling for analytics is mostly new and foreign to me.

I have the following tables:

```
 - Campaign: id, name, etc.
 - Daily_Spending: id, campaign_id, date, spending
 - Daily_Revenue: id, campaign_id, date, revenue
```

I now want to join these tables many_to_one on campaign_id to effectively create a result derived table that looks like:

```
Daily_Campaign_Data: campaign_id, date, spending, revenue
```

Where spending and revenue are effectively NULL or 0 if they did not exist for a specific date.

First of all: Does it make sense to do this just to get a neat table which basically contains all the dates that there was spending and/or revenue going on.

Second: What would be the way to go about this? Since i don't seem to find anything about merging those date fields into one if they co-exist like described.

And Third: Would there be alternatives that make more sense in the database world?

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using?  (2) Provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a list of available dates.  Then use a `cross join` to get the combinations of campaigns and dates and finally `left join`s to bring in the data you want.

Assuming campaign/dates are not duplicated in the spending and revenue tables:

```
select d.date, c.*,
       ds.spending, dr.revenue
from campaign c cross join
     (select date from daily_spending
      union  -- on purpose to remove duplicates
      select date from daily_revenue
     ) d left join
     daily_spending ds
     on ds.campaign_id = c.id and ds.date = d.date left join
     daily_revenue dr
     on dr.campaign_id = c.id and dr.date = d.date;
```

Comment: Spending and Revenue tables never have 2 rows with the exact same campaign_id and date, if that was what you were confirming?
In that case this would be my answer.
Thanks for the clear simple example as well!

Comment: @Smileynator . . . Then this answer should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

For row that don't match you need  left join  and ifnull for obtain  0 value

```
select a.campaign_id, a.date, a.spending, ifNull(b.revenue,0)
from table Campaign c 
left join Daily_Spending a ON c.compain_id = a.compain_id 
left join Daily_Revenuea  b ON c.compain_id = b.compain_id
```